# ORDER BY index not being used due where clause POSTGRES

Tags: postgresql-performance

I have a SQL query generated by JPA:

```
select *
from public.card 
inner join public.affinity_group affinitygr1_ on affinity_group=affinitygr1_.id
inner join public.product product2_ on affinitygr1_.product=product2_.id
inner join public.branch branch3_ on product2_.branch=branch3_.id
inner join public.country country4_ on branch3_.country=country4_.id
    where (country4_.code='ARG' or country4_.code='BRA' or country4_.code='COL' or country4_.code='PER' or country4_.code='MEX' or country4_.code='CHL')
      and branch3_.client_id='cli-qwertyuiop12345'
    order by startDate desc limit 100 offset 1900
```

When I ran this query it took 6 seconds.
We have an index by startDate to boost the query speed.
The problem is that the query is not using the index to order because the query has a WHERE clause. If I remove all the where clauses the query only takes 0.5s.
I cannot use a composite index because the where filter with attributes from another table.

How can i solve this performance issue?

Comment: Could you try to remove the * and select just the ID, for example. In my experience, this could help.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to dba.se! Please provide a) the structures of the tables with indexes (as **text**), and b) the output of `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, VERBOSE, BUFFERS) <your_query>`.

Comment: Try `WHERE country_4 IN ('ARG', 'BRA',.....)`? There's an index on this field? Show us the DDL of relevant tables (at least PKs, JOlNing fields and INDEXes). Put info i to qusstion - notify me using `@` and my handle (no spaces).

Comment: I have an index for the field startDate, but the index is not being used because im filtering in the where

Comment: the Postgres query planner decides what indexes and join algorithms to use based on table statistics. Postgres does not use the index because it thinks this is the fastest way, and it is most probably right. As @Vérace mentioned before, did you try adding an index (b-tree) on country.code, and branch.client_id ?

Comment: @AlexRoitman - please do as I asked - put further information **into the question** and **not** the comments. Table DDL and indexes (as text, not as an image). Then notify me the way I've notified you - `@` + my handle. Better yet, construct a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk) and input some sample data and your result. Please test your fiddle and ensure that the query works as intended - i.e. gives the correct results for your sample data!  The more info you give, the better answers you will receive!